Ubuntu 16.04.5 Black Screen on Setup on a New Laptop
I have to install Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS x64 (Need this exact version) on my new laptop. (Dell G15- i9 13900hx, RTX4060, 32gb ram, 165hz 1080p screen).
When I boot from USB stick i can see the grub menu. When I select "Try Ubuntu" or "Install Ubuntu" i'm getting instant black screen.
I tried everything i see on the internet without success.
What i tried :
-I disabled everything about secure boot & fast boot on bios settings.
-Ubuntu image is not corrupted. Checked it's checksum.
-Burned the iso to USB stick with GPT/MBR partitioning, DD/ISO format. (with Rufus).
-Tried to add nomodeset, nomodset, nouveau.modeset=0 parameters to grub using "E" key.
Is there anything i can try?

The PC is far newer than the Ubuntu 16.04 LTS operating system (OS), and the Dell's hardware is not supported in that OS version.
The practical way to get v. 16.04 on that hardware is to run it inside a virtual machine (VM). The Dell has sufficient computing power to easily handle that task, and that OS in a VM should be responsive.
There are numerous VM's, such as Oracle's free VirtualBox. Many of these run can run on different operating systems, such as Linux or Windows. There are simple directions for installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Desktop on VirtualBox, for example.

Return BIOS settings to

Secure Boot on
Fast Boot off if you plan to use Linux.


Install a modern OS on the Dell PC, whether Windows 10 (only supported for about a year) or 11 (if the machine has the hardware to run it), or Linux, such as Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (with 10 years support).
Install a VM.
Install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in the VM.


N.B.
There are different versions of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS: desktop and server, 32-bit and 64-bit. (16.04 has the last 32-bit installer; it can be upgraded to 18.04, but there is no 32-bit 18.04 installer.) Though you could not run a 32-bit OS directly on 64-bit hardware, you can run it in a VM. Check which version of Ubuntu 16.04 needs to be installed.
